# can I install both Eclipse 3.4 and Eclipse 3.5 simultaneously?

Tags: eclipse

I would like to migrate to Eclipse 3.5 from Eclipse 3.4, but I am working on some critical development and want to make sure I can use 3.4 for a while.

Can I install both of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can. Eclipse is completely self-contained in its "eclipse" directory (of which you can have multiple)

Try to keep separate workspaces, as downgrading later might not work.

Answer (score 1):

You sure can, eclipse doesn't have an installer. When you download it just unzip to different directories.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have any problem with this since they're fairly self-contained. We run Europa and Ganymede side-by-side under Windows just fine. Europa since our reporting solution depends on a specific version of BIRT and Ganymede (soon Galileo) for Java development.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Eclipse distribution is just one zip file that you can extract somewhere you can have as many versions of it around as you wish. It's totally self-contained.